# dealing with missing values with the R filter() function

Tags: r, filter

I'd like to handle missing values using the `filter()` function in R.

In fact, I wish to compute `X_t = 1/(2*T+1) * sum(X_i, i = (t-T)...(t+T))` where `(X_t)` is a classical time series containing missing values. `filter()` computes **sums** over the time intervals `[(t-T);(t+T)]` but it does not give the **mean** of the values excluding the `NA`s.

Does anyone have any idea how about dealing with that?

Comment: Please provide us with sample data and the code you have used so far.  This will make it easier to answer your question.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
library(zoo)
x <- 1:10
x[6] <- NA
rollapply(x, 3, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
## [1] 2.0 3.0 4.0 4.5 6.0 7.5 8.0 9.0
```

There are a variety of other arguments that you may or may not need depending on exactly what you want to get out.  See `?rollapply` .

**REVISED** Have updated answer based on more recent version of `rollapply` which allows simplification.

Answer (score 1):

The sapply trick did not quite work for me. You have to manipulate the initial vector to get it to work with Ks larger than 1. Here is my code:

```
k <- 1  ## Moving average over three points.
x <- c(rep(1,5), NA, rep(1,5)) # input vector
stmp <- c( rep(NA,k), x, rep(NA,k) )
smooth <- sapply((k+1):(k+length(x)), function(i){mean(x[(i-k):(i+k)], na.rm=TRUE)})
```

I also added a function statement so the code runs without error.
Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple moving average over `2k+1` points, you can do this:

```
x <- c(rep(1,5), NA, rep(1,5))
k <- 1  ## Moving average over three points.
smooth <- sapply(1:length(x), mean(x[(i-k):(i+k)], na.rm=TRUE))
```

which results in a vector of all ones in this case.